# Create enum variables inside a singleton class in Java

Tags: java, singleton

I have a singleton class as shown below:

```
public class GlobalClass
{
    public final int _SUCCESS = 0;    
    private static GlobalClass singleton = new GlobalClass( );

    private GlobalClass(){} //Private constructor for Singleton class.

    public static GlobalClass getInstance()
    {
        return singleton;
    }
}
```

I want to create a enum variables. I am not able to do it. I wrote the below code.

```
public class GlobalClass
{
    enum myEnum {
        _ZERO, _ONE, _TWO
    }
    public final int _SUCCESS = 0;
    //public final int _ONE = 1;

    private static GlobalClass singleton = new GlobalClass( );    
    private GlobalClass(){} //Private constructor for Singleton class.

    public static GlobalClass getInstance()
    {
        return singleton;
    }    
}
```

What is wrong with the above?

Comment: Why are you "not able to do it"? What happens? Does the compiler throw an error? Could you provide a *little* bit more information?

Comment: Well ... You obviously declared an enum. So what does "I am not able to do it" exactly mean?

Answer (score 0):

You only declared the enum (which is a special form of a class) inside your `GlobalClass`.

What you are missing is the declaration of the variable with that type as

```
private myEnum _MY_ENUM_INSTANCE;
```

In addition I would recommend that you implement your singleton pattern in a more efficient way as described in [What is an efficient way to implement a singleton pattern in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71399/2846138) (that is also using an enum for some non-obvious reasons.)